# conversion from unsigned int to int, possible loss of data

Tags: c++, console, sfml

I was trying to create a vertex array for my tilemap. I followed this tutorial I found in a book. there shuldn't be any error yet this thing sttill pops up: "Argument: conversion from unsigned int to int, possible loss of data". I don't understand this error, can someone tell me what the problem is?
here's the code:

Tilemap.h

```
    class TileMap : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:
    bool Load(const std::string &tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, const int* tiles, unsigned int width, unsigned int height) 
    {
        //Loads the tileset texture.
        if (!m_tileset.loadFromFile(tileset))
            return false;

        //Resize the vertex array to fit the level size.
        m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
        m_vertices.resize(width * height * 4);

        //Populates the vertex array with one quad per tile.
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
            {
                //Get the current tile number.
                int tileNumber = tiles[i + j * width];

                //Find its position in the tileset texture.
                int tu = tileNumber % (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);
                int tv = tileNumber / (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);

                //Get a pointer to the current tile quad.
                sf::Vertex* quad = &m_vertices[(i + j * width) * 4];

                //Define its 4 corners.
                quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);

                //Define its 4 texture coordinates.
                quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
            }
        return true;
    }
private:

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {   
        //Applies the entity's transform.
        states.transform *= getTransform(); 

        //Applies the texture.
        states.texture = &m_tileset;

        //Draw the vertex array.
        target.draw(m_vertices, states);
    }
    //Constructor
    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Texture m_tileset;
};`
```

main.ccp

```
int main()
{
    //Window Stuff
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(512, 256), "Shattered Soul"); //creates the window.

    window.setFramerateLimit(60); //establishes the frame rate limit.

    //Tile Map
    //Defines the level with an array of tile indices.
    const int level[] =
    {
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    bool playerUp, playerDown, playerLeft, playerRight = false;

    //Initializes Classes
    Player playerObject;
    TileMap tileMap;
    if (!tileMap.Load("graphics/tileset.png", sf::Vector2u(32, 32), level, 16, 8))
        return -1;

    //Loads the player sprite.
    sf::Texture playerTexture;
    playerTexture.loadFromFile("graphics/player.png");
    sf::Sprite playerSprite(playerTexture);
    playerSprite.setPosition(340, 220);
    

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        //Processes events.
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
            //Enables player to exit the game using the Esc button.
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape) {
                window.close();
            }
        }
        //Enables user to move the player via keyboard.
        playerRight = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right);
        playerLeft = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left);
        playerUp = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up);
        playerDown = sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down);

        //Updates the player movement
        playerObject.update(playerUp, playerDown, playerLeft, playerRight);
        
        window.clear(); //Clears the window with a white color.

        window.draw(tileMap);
        window.draw(playerSprite); // Draws the player sprite.

        playerSprite.move(sf::Vector2f(playerObject.xvel, playerObject.yvel));
        
        window.display();
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I'm so sorry guys if I kind of wasted your time. Actually the reason that the vertex array didn't work is due to a simple stupid mistake, I accidentally duplicated a code that shouldn't be there.

I changed this particular line of code from:

```
 //Define its 4 corners.
                quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);

                //Define its 4 texture coordinates.
                quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
            }
```

To this:

```
 //Define its 4 texture coordinates.
                quad[0].texCoordinates = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[1].texCoordinates = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
                quad[2].texCoordinates = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
                quad[3].texCoordinates = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
```

Basically I just substituted the "position" code into "texCoordinates" because it was supposed to be denoting the texture coordinate not the corners. The "position" variable is only valid for former part of the code.

Comment: It also tells you the exact line where that happens. Can you copy that line and put that in a separate code box in the question please?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking this is because signed and unsigned types can represent different ranges of numbers. For example an unsigned 8 bit integer can hold the number range [0:255], whereas a signed 8 bit integer can hold the range [-128:127].

As long as your number is within the common range [0:127] there is no problem, but negatives cannot be represented in an unsigned type, and values above 127 cannot be represented in a signed.

If your compiler cannot prove that the value you are trying to convert is in the common range, it will give the "possible loss of data" warning, and then it is up to you to figure out if it is a real problem (and fix it), or if you yourself can guarantee that there is no problem.

This is how it works with all numeric types (that I can think of at the moment), the only difference is what the possible ranges are. F.ex. for a 32 bit integer the signed range is [-2147483648 : 2147483647] and the unsigned range is [0 : 4294967295].

Comment: "_...whereas a signed 8 bit integer can hold the range [-128:127]_" - since C++20 (where _Two's complement_ signed integers are mandated). Prior to C++20, [-127,127]` was also a valid range.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Wait, the full two's complement range wasn't required before C++20? I guess you learn something new every day.

Comment: Yes, it took some time - and signed integer overflow is _still_ undefined behavior. It was proposed that it should be made defined - but they decided to drop that.